# Jenkins - Build failed - Parameters are not passed to Gradle

Tags: gradle, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I have a step for 'upload' in my `Jenkins` job.
This step should upload the artifact to `Nexus`, this stage is working fine.

The issue comes in when i'm trying to pass parameters to the `Gradle` side, it returns me this error:

> ---
>
> groupParam =
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - Where: Build file '/var/jenkins_home/workspace/Pipeline with Gradle/build.gradle' line: 33
> - What went wrong: A problem occurred configuring root project 'myFirstApp'.
>
>   > Could not get unknown property 'groupParam' for task ':roeyUpload' of type org.gradle.api.tasks.Upload.
> - Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
> - Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
>
> Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it
>   incompatible with Gradle 5.0. Use '--warning-mode all' to show the
>   individual deprecation warnings. See
>   https://docs.gradle.org/4.10/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
>
> BUILD FAILED in 19s [Pipeline] } [Pipeline] // stage [Pipeline] }
>   [Pipeline] // node [Pipeline] End of Pipeline ERROR: script returned
>   exit code 1 Finished: FAILURE

The code from Jenkins job:

```
stage('Push to Nexus') {        
    echo 'Start push to Nexus...'   
    sh 'chmod +x gradle'    
    sh './gradle  -PgroupParam=123 -PversionParam=456 upload --info'            
    echo 'End push to Nexus...' 
}
```

The code in `Gradle`:

```
uploadArchives {

    println "******************************************************************************"
    println "groupParam = "
    println "$groupParam"   <<<<<  line #33
    println "versionParam = "
    println "$versionParam"
    println "******************************************************************************"

    repositories {
        mavenDeployer {
            repository(url: "http://125.27.4.1:8080/repository/test1/") {
                authentication(userName: "abcdef", password: "abcdef")
            }
            snapshotRepository(url: "http://125.27.4.1:8080/repository/test1/") {
                authentication(userName: "abcdef", password: "abcdef")
            }
        }
    }    
}
```

Could anyone please tell me what i'm doing wrong here ?

Why these params are not being passed to the `Gradle` side ?

Is it related to versions of plugins and Jenkins?

Comment: try this: `println "${project.groupParam}"`

Comment: @daggett returns the same, do I need to declare on those params? is it related to versions of plugins and Jenkins?

Comment: could not be the same - as minimum accessor is different )

Comment: what is `project`? how it's defined ? I don't this variable in my code, is it global?

Comment: global. https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/writing_build_scripts.html

Comment: Does using `getProperty('groupParam')` in Gradle help?

Comment: @Jazzschmidt no.. returns the same error

Comment: I'm wondering about the `./gradle` script. Did you rename it from the Gradle Wrapper `gradlew`?

Comment: yes, I actually running with `gradlew` and not `gradle`